# How could i use methods to work with pointers massive?

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

i have tried to get some work done and suddenly realized that i don't know how to send an pointer argument to method correctly. Was looking for same problem around the web but didn't find any better solutions.
my code is:

```
    TextBook *lib[50];

lib[0]=new TextBook(arg1, arg2, arg3);
lib[1]=new TextBook(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

and my function is:

```
void libPrint(Textbook *lib){
    cout<<lib[0]->getArg1();
    cout<<lib[0]->getArg2();
    // etc..
}
```

but libPrint method generates "triggered break point" error, but i didn't make any breakpoints, so maybe it caused by using pointers in some inappropriate or just simply syntax-incorrect way.

So my answer is: how could I rewrite libPrint method to make it work correctly?

Comment: Stop using pointers. It's not java and it's not C. You don't need to make things that difficult in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should look like

```
void libPrint(Textbook **lib){
    cout<<lib[0]->getArg1();
    cout<<lib[0]->getArg2();
    // etc..
}
```

That is if you have an array like

```
T lib[50];
```

where T is some type then when it is passed to a function by value the array name is converted to pointer to its first element

```
void libPrint( T *lib );
```

Here withing the function parameter `lib` has type `T *`

Now simply substitute `T` for the type of element of your array

```
TextBook * lib[50];
```

`T` is equal to `TextBook *`. So the pointer to the first element of the array will have type `Textbook **`.

These three function declarations

```
void libPrint(Textbook * lib[50] );
void libPrint(Textbook * lib[] );
void libPrint(Textbook **lib );
```

are equivalent and declare the same one function.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use pointers at all? I would recommend something like:

```
// Declare your vector
std::vector<TextBook> lib;

// Add TextBooks
lib.emplace_back(arg1, arg2, arg3);
lib.emplace_back(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

And for your print function

```
void libPrint(std::vector<TextBook> const& lib)
{
    // Loop over each book and print arguments
    for (auto const& book : lib)
    {
        cout << book.getArg1() << endl;
        cout << book.getArg2() << endl;
        cout << book.getArg3() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention: in my specific task i am not alloved to use std::vector. 
i see how it could work much easier, but meh :(

Comment: @prazza: You should understand that `std::vector` has been part of C++ since 1998. Your teacher is teaching you a style that's been outdated for 17 years. Yes, it's possible to use pointers - that's the result of C++ heritage in C and its backwards compatibility.

Comment: @MSalters: I'we asked him about this before, but he replied: "you should know how it works from inside". We coded our own "vector" class at the previous classes, so im not surprised by this restriction at all.

Comment: @prazza: Ah, that's relevant. Why not use your own vector class then? (I still disagree with the order - you should learn how the inside works after you know how it works from the outside)

Comment: @MSalters hm, maybe i should try to make my current task done by using my pre-made "vector", teacher might appreciate this. Thx for advise.

About what to learn first, -in or outside : I think, thats the right spot, but im not sure, that proffesor would change his 20-years experienced way of teaching right after remark from a young padavan of IT, we probably will just go to using std::vector right after this few tasks, though.

Comment: "We coded our own "vector" class" - then use that, if `std::vector` isn't allowed. Writing a vector is a good way to understand how memory management works; trying to juggle pointers while implementing program logic is not, it's just a recipe for mistakes.